# How to set comparator for comparing maven artifact versions when implementing a plugin?

Tags: maven, versioning, maven-plugin, artifact

Initially I thought of using versions-maven-plugin to automatically update versions of maven artifacts, but then I found out that it doesn't fit according to the versions we are using in our company. I want to either modify this plugin or create my own goals to include in it (or create a new plugin) so that I can update the versions automatically. So here is my questions:

How would I go to implement my own comparator for artifacts, so that I can use existing Versions Maven Plugin API to get the latest versions from repository? For example,

```
org.codehaus.mojo.versions.api.AbstractVersionDetails
```

has `getNewestVersion` method to get the latest version, but how can I specify how to compare artifacts?

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

This is the format we use for versioning: MAJOR.MINOR.INCREMENTAL.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Here, MAJOR is XX, MINOR is Y, INCREMENTAL is Z, and build is AB, where X,Y,Z,A,B are digits. For eks. 54.1.0.1-SNAPSHOT. The most important thing is that when updating a version, the MAJOR.MINOR.INCREMENTAL part must be the same for both the current and the updated version, and this is because of branches.

Comment: Take a look at `DefaultVersionsHelper` class. Can you also describe why versions plugin doesn't fit into your structure? I've used it to do some things in my plugin and it saved me a ton of time.

Comment: Please see the *EDIT* in description. I have seen the class you refer to, and I see there are different version comparators, but I just want to see if anybody has any good ideas, and whether there is any need to reinventing the wheel if the plugin acutally supports my format. One thing that is clear is that MavenVersionComparator cannot be used here.

Answer (score 0):

You have read that documentation [here](http://mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html).

Comment: Yes, I have read, but there is very little further information. In my case, the version is MAJOR.MINOR.INCREMENTAL.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Why do you need that part "BUILD" ? Usually this is not needed in particular in relationship with SNAPSHOT.